# Draw circle in new position without removing previous circle?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, picturebox

In fact , I want to draw circle in new position each time double-click and without remove before circle ,It should be noted that, I used `PictureBox`.

```
public Point postionCursor { get; set; }
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    postionCursor = this.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 25, Cursor.Position.Y - 25));
    points.Add(postionCursor);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();

    pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pic_Paint);
}

private void pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
       g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    foreach (Point pt in points)
    {

        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Tomato, 2);
        SolidBrush myb = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        g.DrawEllipse(p, postionCursor.X, postionCursor.Y, 20, 20);
        g.FillEllipse(myb, postionCursor.X, postionCursor.Y, 20, 20);
        p.Dispose();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Then paint the ~before~circle also in the paint event.

Comment: `pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pic_Paint);` should be in your form load or constructor.

Comment: @RezaAghaei,why should be used only in constructor ? and Explain a little more?

Comment: You need to subscribe for the event only once. If you subscribe for the event more than once, every time the event occurs the method which you registered as event handler will execute and all codes of method will execute again and again. It makes your application slow.

Comment: @RezaAghaei,your explanations were excellent.thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the `pt` variable in the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (Point pt in points)
{
    using(Pen p = new Pen(Color.Tomato, 2))
    using(SolidBrush myb = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
    {
        g.FillEllipse(myb, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);
        g.DrawEllipse(p, pt.X, pt.Y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

In your code, you were just overwriting the circle in the same location for every `Point` in the `points` list.

Also, as Reza mentioned in the comments, you don't need to attach the `PaintEventHandler` event hanlder every time the PictureBox is clicked, you just need to do it once.

Comment: That's it +1. Also the OP should put `pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pic_Paint);` in form load or constructor. Also he should first `Fill` and then Draw ellipse. Aslo he need to `Dispose` brush too. It's better to use `using` for both pen and brush.

Comment: You could also try only invalidating the region of the PictureBox where the click occurred (and the surrounding box 20x20px) to improve performance and reduce flicker.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzka3b5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StuartMeeks -  Nice optimisation, hadn't thought of that

Comment: _you just need to do it once_ that is putting it mildly:  multiple calls will result making the app more and more sluggish!

Answer (score 0):

So I got to thinking, and then Visual Studio-ing, that perhaps we don't even need the foreach loop. I still maintain a List so we know where the user has clicked, but there's no need to loop through it and redraw everything every time.

I realize this doesn't handle the case where the underlying list is modified, but nor does the original sample. Here's my entire Form1 class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int CircleDiameter = 20;
    private const int PenWidth = 2;

    private readonly List<Point> _points = new List<Point>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Paint += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _points.ForEach(p => DrawPoint(p, args.Graphics));
        };
    }

    private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cursorLocation = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        _points.Add(cursorLocation);

        var circleArea = new Rectangle(
            cursorLocation.X - CircleDiameter/2 - PenWidth,
            cursorLocation.Y - CircleDiameter/2 - PenWidth,
            CircleDiameter + PenWidth*2,
            CircleDiameter + PenWidth*2);

        pictureBox1.Invalidate(circleArea);
    }

    private static void DrawPoint(Point point, Graphics graphics)
    {
        point.X -= CircleDiameter / 2;
        point.Y -= CircleDiameter / 2;

        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Tomato, PenWidth))
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
        {
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, point.X, point.Y, CircleDiameter, CircleDiameter);
            graphics.FillEllipse(brush, point.X, point.Y, CircleDiameter, CircleDiameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**
So I updated the code to use the Paint event which has the foreach loop. However, I don't Invalidate (and Paint) every time a circle is added - there's no need for that. Just adding a circle by drawing means the control only invalidates and re-paints the region where the new circle was added.

Try setting a breakpoint on the DrawAllPoints method. You'll see it only happens during full invalidation operations such as minimizing and restoring.

**Update 2:**
After further chat, I agree the Invalidate method is superior. Code updated to use Invalidate with a rectangle to invalidate.

And now it's looking very much like the OP :)

Comment: I'm done coding, but I wonder if this could be turned into an extension method on the Control class so we can do it to, say, a Panel rather than a PictureBox. Food for thought :)

Comment: Try to minimize the window and restore it again and see the result. All paintings will disappear.

Comment: Always you should put painting codes in `Paint` event handler.

Comment: In double click event you only need to call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` then it will cause the `Paint` event raise and since you handled it this way: `_points.ForEach(p => DrawPoint(p, args.Graphics));` all points will be drawn. Calling your `DrawPoint` method passing `pictureBox1.CreateGraphics` to it pointless. Also now you are using a `Loop` too :) same as the OP.

Comment: My double click event only draws a single circle and does not invalidate. This means it will perform better than invalidating on every double-click and drawing all circles every time.

Instead I save invalidation for when it's really required, such as during minimize/restore operations.

Comment: The correct solution is using `Invalidate`, but choosing the solution is up to you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117097/discussion-between-stuart-meeks-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Here is a good place for knowledge sharing. Hope you find my comments in that direction and hope my comments don't offend you  :)